# What is the criteria for requesting cards?

Tags: clash-royale

I have been playing Clash Royale from a couple of weeks ago with XP Level 4 and 711 trophies in Arena 2. I have a Prince card in my deck, but I am unable to request a Prince card from my clan mates. What is the criteria for requesting cards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Epic cards, like Prince, can only be requested on Sundays.

> On Epic Sundays, you are allowed to request Epic cards once. The number of Epics you can request at one time is equal to the number of Rares you can request.
>
> Legendaries cannot be requested.
>
> You will receive 1 XP and 5 Gold for each Common card donated or 10 XP and 50 Gold for each Rare card donated. For every Epic card donated, you get 10 XP and 500 Gold.

Source: [Clash Royale wiki, "Clans - Donations and Requests"](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Clans#Donations_and_Requests)

Here's the full mechanics on card requests / donations:

> Clan Members can request Common, or Rare cards once every 7 hours with Epics available on Sunday. Cards received depend on your Arena level and card class:
>
> Goblin Stadium
> Donations – 1 Common or 1 Rare
> Requests – 10 Commons or 1 Rare
>
> Bone Pit
> Donations – 2 Commons or 1 Rare
> Requests - 10 Commons or 1 Rare
>
> Barbarian Bowl
> Donations – 2 Commons or 1 Rare
> Requests – 10 Commons or 1 Rare
>
> P.E.K.K.A.’s Playhouse
> Donations – 4 Commons or 1 Rare
> Requests – 20 Commons or 2 Rares
>
> Spell Valley
> Donations – 4 Commons or 1 Rare
> Requests – 20 commons or 2 Rares
>
> Builder’s Workshop
> Donations – 4 Commons or 1 Rare
> Requests – 20 Commons or 2 Rares
>
> Royal Arena
> Donations – 6 Commons or 1 Rare
> Requests – 30 Commons or 3 Rares
>
> Frozen Peak
> Donations – 6 Commons or 1 Rare
> Requests – 30 Commons or 3 Rares
>
> Jungle Arena
> Donations – 6 Commons or 1 Rare
> Requests – 30 Commons or 3 Rares
>
> Hog Mountain
> Donations – 8 Commons or 1 Rare
> Requests – 40 Commons or 4 Rares.
>
> Electro Valley
> Donations – 8 Commons or 1 Rare
> Requests – 40 Commons or 4 Rares.
>
> Legendary Arena
> Donations – 8 Commons or 1 Rare
> Requests – 40 Commons or 4 Rares.
>
> You cannot receive entirely new cards by request. It’s necessary to first discover them through Chests.
>
> Donating cards also gives you Gold and XP:
> Common > +5 Gold & 1 XP
> Rare > +50 Gold & 5 XP

Source: [Supercell Support's Card Request / Donation article](https://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-royale/?s=cards-chests&f=card-request-donation)

Answer (score 3):

Epic cards can now be requested once every Sunday and like rares, you can get up to 4 of them at a time. You do still have to own the card to request it, but you can also get a free random epic from the shop every Sunday.